# traverse the inputs in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

in my `*ngFor` I create item dynamically and within these are
some inputs, so well, what I need is how I can traverse those inputs
when I implement my save button. I need help or some suggestion.
If I create the inputs dynamically

```
<ion-list item-start *ngFor="let nivel of niveles" id="asistencia">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label color="primary" class="niveles">{{nivel.nivel}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-label color="danger" class="niveles">{{nivel.codigoModular}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Docentes que deben Asistir</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        <ion-icon color="primary" name="school"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="number">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Docentes que Asistierón</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        <ion-icon color="primary" name="school"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="number">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Alumnos que deben Asistir</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        <ion-icon color="danger" name="contacts"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="number">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Alumnos que Asistierón</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>
                        <ion-icon color="danger" name="contacts"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="number">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using [**Ionic and Forms**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/).

You can do it using either `2-way data binding` or `reactive form` method.Please refer the above official doc.

This is just an example.Hope you can convert it to your use case:

*2-way data binding method:*

*.html*

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Todo</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todo.title" name="title"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="todo.description" name="description"></ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>
      <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Todo</button>
    </form>
```

*.ts*

```
export class FormsPage {
  todo = {}
  logForm() {
    console.log(this.todo)
  }
}
```

Comment: you did not understand me, I generate the items dynamically and these well with inputs and those inputs I have to read with a button

Comment: Yes, You need to define your model as shown above and then use that model with the save button `logForm() {
    console.log(this.todo)
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but I've forked a Stackblitz created by ConnorsFan to solve a dynamic form issue that I had. 
The form template in staffFormInfo drives the form. The dynamic form stackblitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymvaml)

ConnorsFan's original post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139918/why-is-ionic-3-two-way-data-binding-not-working/49141207#49141207).

Please let me know if this helps...