# Why is ionic 3 two way data binding not working?

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, ionic3, ngmodel

please I'm trying to flesh out a registration page for my ionic ongoing project 
Trying to bind my  ([ngModel]) to an object property in my component.

Let me just show the code excerpt so you'll understand

```
**Registration.ts** // This is my registration component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-registration',
  templateUrl: 'registration.html',
})

export class RegistrationPage {
  newStaffInfo = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      rePassword: "",
      email: "",
      sex: ""
  }


newStaffTemplateObject: Object = [
      {
        label: "Username",
        field: this.newStaffInfo.username,
      },

      {
        label: "Password",
        field: this.newStaffInfo.password  
      },

      {
        label: "Re-enter Your password",
        field: this.newStaffInfo.rePassword  
      },
      {
        label: "Email",
        field: this.newStaffInfo.email  
      },

      {
        label: "Sex",
        field: this.newStaffInfo.sex  
      },

  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegistrationPage');
  }


  validateForm(){
      console.log("Validate in this functin...");
  }
}
```

This is my HTML Template

```
<ion-content padding>

    <form (ngSubmit)="validateForm()" #form="ngForm">
        <ion-list>

            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of newStaffTemplateObject">
                <ion-label floating> {{item.label}} </ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.field" name="item.label" #item.label="ngModel" required> </ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <button ion-button outline block full> Register </button>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-list>
    </form>

<!-- For DEbugging puprpose only -->

{{newStaffInfo.username}}  //This is suppose to reflect changes immediately
</ion-content>
```

Even with the above setup, it's not working at all. 
What can i do here to make the two data binding work

Comment: No error messages in the console?

Comment: There's none. It renders correctly. Just doesn't bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you initialize the `newStaffTemplateObject` items with the properties of `newStaffInfo`:

```
newStaffTemplateObject = [
  {
    label: "Username",
    field: this.newStaffInfo.username
  },
  {
    label: "Password",
    field: this.newStaffInfo.password
  },
  ...
];
```

and then you bind the `newStaffTemplateObject` items to the input elements in the template.

The data binding works: it updates the values of the `newStaffTemplateObject` items. However, it does not update the related properties in `newStaffInfo` (which is what you expected, according to your debugging markup). The reason: `newStaffTemplateObject[0].field` does not become a reference to `newStaffInfo.username`; it is a separate variable that does not maintain any link with it after having been initialized.

One possible solution is to set each `field` value to the name of the property in `newStaffInfo`:

```
newStaffTemplateObject = [
  {
    label: "Username",
    field: "username",
  },
  {
    label: "Password",
    field: "password"
  },
  {
    label: "Re-enter password",
    field: "rePassword"
  },
  {
    label: "Email",
    field: "email"
  },
  {
    label: "Sex",
    field: "sex"
  },
];
```

and to bind the properties of `newStaffInfo` to your input elements using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of newStaffTemplateObject">
  ...
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newStaffInfo[item.field]" ... > </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

You can test the code in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tsqsh).

Comment: Wow! a big wow to this solution. That's a very elegant solution.
one questions though.
1.. This means you're referencing these objects with array indexes. ?

Comment: Not with array indexes, but rather with the property name. I added a link to [this MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), where you can find more details about property accessors.

Answer (score 1):

*This is showing up as a separate answer since I'm not able to add a comment to Connorsfan's answer.*

Connorsfan's answer was very helpful for my initial issue and pointed me in the direction of Stackblitz, Thank you!

I also ran into an interesting issue down the road, trying to navigate multi-level json and use a truly dynamic form.

Built on the stackblitz from ConnorsFan to add dynamic data binding with multi-level support as the banana-in-the-box [(ngModel)] doesn't work when using expressions to handle multi-level json. Can be found at this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymvaml

Hopefully, this will help others facing the same problem but with multi-level json.

Comment: Please refer [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Though this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes